# How to find Inverse Cumulative Distribution Function of discrete functions in Python

Tags: python, numpy, inverse, cdf

I am trying to find the Inverse CDF function of  discrete probability distribution in Python and then plot it.  My CDF is derived from the following numpy output:

```
array([ 0.228157,  0.440671,  0.588515,  0.683326,  0.740365,  0.783288,
        0.81362 ,  0.840518,  0.859213,  0.876764,  0.889355,  0.89813 ,
        0.909194,  0.916443,  0.9256  ,  0.930369,  0.938572,  0.942387,
        0.946012,  0.951353,  0.954405,  0.956694,  0.965088,  0.966614,
        0.96814 ,  0.969475,  0.970047,  0.971001,  0.971573,  0.973099,
        0.974816,  0.975388,  0.977105,  0.984163,  0.984354,  0.984736,
        0.98569 ,  0.985881,  0.986072,  0.986644,  0.990269,  0.990651,
        0.990842,  0.993322,  0.993704,  0.994467,  0.995039,  0.995802,
        0.996184,  0.996375,  0.996566,  0.996757,  0.997329,  0.99752 ,
        0.997711,  0.997902,  0.998093,  0.998284,  0.998475,  0.998666,
        0.998857,  0.999239,  0.999621,  0.999812,  1.00000])
```

I tried `rv_discrete.ppf(q, *args, **kwds)`, but it works for random variables, which is not my case.

Comment: Are you referring to the quantile function? There's a pandas function for that: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html

Comment: Yes, I think quantile function would work for me.

Comment: The last entry of the CDF is 1.000003? o_O

Comment: yes, but you can change it to 1.000,I did so :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you have lots of points perhaps you would find linear interpolation acceptable between adjacent points. Do binary search to find the points that are adjacent to the probability you seek in the first place. Like this, with some tidying up:

```
import numpy as np

CDF = np.array([ 0.228157, 0.440671, 0.588515, 0.683326, 0.740365, 0.783288, 0.81362 , 0.840518, 0.859213, 0.876764, 0.889355, 0.89813 , 0.909194, 0.916443, 0.9256 , 0.930369, 0.938572, 0.942387, 0.946012, 0.951353, 0.954405, 0.956694, 0.965088, 0.966614, 0.96814 , 0.969475, 0.970047, 0.971001, 0.971573, 0.973099, 0.974816, 0.975388, 0.977105, 0.984163, 0.984354, 0.984736, 0.98569 , 0.985881, 0.986072, 0.986644, 0.990269, 0.990651, 0.990842, 0.993322, 0.993704, 0.994467, 0.995039, 0.995802, 0.996184, 0.996375, 0.996566, 0.996757, 0.997329, 0.99752 , 0.997711, 0.997902, 0.998093, 0.998284, 0.998475, 0.998666, 0.998857, 0.999239, 0.999621, 0.999812, 1.00000] )

## inverse of .3
index = np.searchsorted(CDF, .3) 
print ( index )
print ( (.3 - CDF [ index-1 ] ) / ( CDF [ index ] - CDF [ index-1 ] ) )
```

Output is this.

```
1
0.338062433534
```